# Do we have a phrase expressing that you have to look around, back, down and up to make sure you won't fall, trip, sleep, or bump into things?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

When my children walk on a road or a place with many objects around, I often tell them to:

- **look down**: to make sure they don't trip over or slip on something.
- **look up**: to make sure they don't bump their heads on something dangling in the air like a light bulb or some wood sticking out on a construction site.
- **look behind**: in case there is a vehicle behind them. The vehicle might hit them from behind.

I often hear people say "**eyes on the road**" but that doesn't cover the one behind or up in the air.

**Do we have a phrase expressing that you have to look around, back, down and up to make sure you won't fall, trip, sleep, or bump into things?**

For example, is "**watch out for everything**" a natural way to say it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Be careful" would seem to cover all cases, and "Look around you", and "Watch out for hazards".

"What sort of hazards do you mean, dad?" they ask. And you can explain as above.

"Eyes on the road" is advice particularly for drivers, who may get distracted by someone or something in the car (friends, radio, sat-nav, mobile etc)

Comment: It depends on how urgent the warning needs to be. If you spot a danger that the child appears to be oblivious of, then **"Look out!"** might be appropriate.